# Symfony 5 - Filter some entities from DB for a collectionType

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form based on a collection. I would like that form to be set with a part of the data I have in my entity (not all).
I have search but haven't find the answer I'm looking for.
I tought using PRE_SET_DATA but the way I understand it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to do that?

I have an entity Service

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ServiceRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ServiceRepository::class)
 */
class Service
{
    //[...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="services")
     */
    private $performer;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="performer_services")
     */
    private $service_performer;


    //[...]

    public function getPerformer(): ?user
    {
        return $this->performer;
    }

    public function setPerformer(?user $performer): self
    {
        $this->performer = $performer;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getServicePerformer(): ?User
    {
        return $this->service_performer;
    }

    public function setServicePerformer(?User $service_performer): self
    {
        $this->service_performer = $service_performer;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Collection Form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class PerformerServiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('performer_services',CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type' => ServicePerformerNoMoneyUnitType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
            ->add('enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
        ;
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Entity Form (based on Service)

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Service;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use App\Entity\User;

class ServicePerformerNoMoneyUnitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class, [
                'currency' => false])
            ->add('servicePerformer', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\User',
                'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findByPartners($this->security->getUser());
                },
            ])
            ->add('description')
        ;
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $service = $event->getData();
            $userService = new User;
            $performerService = new User;
            if ($service <> null)
            {
                $userService = $service->getPerformer();
                dump($userService);
                $performerService = $service->getServicePerformer();
                dump($performerService);
            }

            $form = $event->getForm();

            // checks if the Product object is "new"
            // If no data is passed to the form, the data is "null".
            // This should be considered a new "Product"
            if ($userService == $performerService) {
                $form->removeElement();
            }
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Service::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is not show rows where Performer = Service Performer.